# Will I be rejected or selected based on my below interview case?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, reinterviewing

I had an interview recently, where I cleared my first round with ease.The first round lasted for 40 minutes and the person said he will give his feedback to the HR and they will get back to me. I had some other works for the day so I chose to travel out of town. On the way I got another call where the same interviewer said his onsite mate wants to conduct another round of interview in next 30 minute. I told him am traveling and will be available after 2 hrs. He called me after 2 hours and connected to the onsite person.

He asked me a few questions related to my technology. I answered them all. But from his words only it seemed he was having a lot of arrogance and attitude. Unnecessarily he was trying to say something which was irrelevant to my answers. But when he cross questioned me I answered all the questions correctly and with a lot of confidence. The round lasted for 20 minutes which was less than the first round. Atlast he  said I don't have any other questions, do you have to ask anything? 
I said him what kind of activities they do for the tool which I was being interviewed  for.
His answer appeared a bit negative to me. **Here is what he said** "First of all we in our organization don't work on that tool, we have been asked by client to work on it". **This statement itself showed the bad approach(over smartness)  of the interviewer as it is obvious noone will go that deep while asking question, you need to understand it. No service company will work on a tool out of time pass it will work for client only.**

**The second thing** while ending he said  "we work for all these activities in the tool and so we are looking for someone who has good understanding about the tool". Both these statements that he used didn't sound good to me and so I think my chances of selection is slim. If I am rejected I don't know for what cause I am getting rejected. Is it because I answered all the questions or is it because he is having some superiority complex.

Can anyone suggest me whether I will get selected or rejected in the interview. It has been one day I have given the interview and haven't heard anyone. If rejected then why and if selected then why?

Comment: We cannot predict the future.  A company can hire somebody because the intervee likes a particular sports team or not hire them because they like a particular sports team.  In many cases you will never know the reason you were not selected.

Comment: @Ramhound : True it happens mostly because many interviewers think they are superior as the candidates rely on them or their approval to pass the interview. It is a general tendency, they say this is professional world but it is more often too personal. Such interviewers must be identified and sacked from the organization so that no one misuses their post.

Comment: I am not saying its right.  I am just saying that you could know nothing about the subject material, but if interviewers like your personality, they could select you.  Likewise if they don't like your personality they could decide not to select you.  **knowlege can be taught** you cannot train personality.

Comment: It's just an interview. You probably didn't get the job this time. Just shrug it off and prepare for the next one.

Comment: @TheMathemagician : Thankyou for the supporting words. Ya you are right...

Answer (score 2):

Knowing only what you described above is only (less than) half of the story. Without the other half we can only make guesses. And guessing based on one-sided information usually don't help, rather the contrary. It's easy (and tempting) to make assumptions about the thoughts or motivation(s) of people based on their current attitude or words. However, more often than not our quick and instinctive assumptions prove to be wrong. That person may have had a bad day, a toothache, or you may have reminded him/her to a bad memory from his/her past, triggering a counteroffensive reaction, etc. etc.

IMHO it is better not to put too much emphasis on this. You did your best during these interviews, now they are going to make their decision based on that (and a lot of other factors you and us are unaware of). If you don't get called within, say, 3 days, it may be a good idea to politely inquire by mail or phone. Then you will get an answer.

If they select you to move forward in the application process, your doubts may prove to be unfounded.

If OTOH you happen to be rejected, it may also be of several reasons. They may have simply found a better candidate. Or they have reevaluated their plans and are looking for someone with different skills / qualifications. But if they reject you based on the opinion of a single interviewer who apparently had a bad day, and/or a bad rapport with you and/or is an unpleasant person in general, this is probably not the company you would be happy to work with in the long term anyway, so you may consider it lucky that it ended this fast :-)

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph: if that's the person you're going to be working with, do you want this job?

Comment: @Peter Torok :-) thanks for your thoughts, it was real nice. Ya that's true, I am not much serious about it. Because from my end I made everything right so it was truly unpleasant to get something wrong without a fault of mine...But yes waiting is the best idea, sometimes when we follow up too much then the other party(company or consultant) gets a feeling that we desperately need the job so they have tendency to misuse us and our offer as per their convenience and terms.

Comment: @Philip Kendall :Definitely not, even I was also thinking the same this week end because if before giving offer they are speaking in this tone then after giving the offer or after I join the company they may just harass me which is not at all a pleasant situation

Comment: Right, so if you don't want to work for this company, why do you care whether they call you back or not? Just let them know you're not interested in the role any more and move on.

Comment: @foni, you won't get the job sometimes even with a great interview. You are in competition with other people. If they have 3 greate people to choose from , you may have answered everything correctly sand still not get the job. People seem to forget that interviewing is not about how well they did but about well well they did in comparison to the other candidates.